How can default scp transfer protocol be overriden besides -O option?
Changes to default behavior of scp from openSSH version 8 to version 9 require using scp with -O option to override the default use of the SFTP protocol. How can scp be configured to use the older protocol by default?
It should be possible to do this in the user's ~/.ssh/config file, even for specific hosts, but I cannot figure out how, or even if it's possible. I'd be satisfied if it were available globally in /etc/ssh somewhere too, if not possible in ~/.ssh/config.
However I found an alternative to the ssh -O option that works (see superuser) ssh -o "PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa", but couldn't figure out how to add that to my ~/.ssh/config file which the OP of that post implied could work.
The -o option doesn't revert to using scp protocol instead of the new default sftp protocol, but did resolve the connection issue I experienced. As with the -O option, I don't think it's possible to use that option in the ~/.ssh/config file, thus the wrapper approach seems to be the best way to handle this problem. Whether the -O or -o option is used in the wrapper is up to your own assessment of the problem.

As of the (current) OpenSSH 9.8, the only way to switch to the legacy SCP mode, is using the -O switch.
There's no other say, neither using config nor anything else.
You can create an scp alias or wrapper script though.
See scp -O (legacy protocol) option per config file? on Super User.
